# Pronunciation of "créer"

Tags: prononciation, accents-régionaux, dialectes

I used to think that pronouncing the verb "créer" like "créyer" was a specificity of West African French, but recently heard it said by a Morrocan and a Normand.

What is the most common pronunciation of "créer"?
In general, which dialects usually add "y" between two "é"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most used pronunciation of "créer" (and considered correct in France French) is [kʀee].

As far as I know, it's pretty common for people who have Arabic as their first language to add a *y* sound, because the *é* sound is absent from their language. Because of that, pronouncing two in a row can be hard.

Comment: Upvote for the first part of the answer, which already answers the question. The second part might be correct, I don't know...

Comment: Oui, c'est juste ce que j'ai observé personnellement, ça vaut ce que ça vaut. Ce serait intéressant d'avoir le point de vue de quelqu'un dont la langue maternelle est l'arabe.